Looking for a Particular Lattice Model of an SPT
I was wondering if anyone knew of some examples of lattice models of a symmetry protected topological (SPT) state with a protected $U(1)$ symmetry in 2+1d. I'd be curious about lattice models for either fermions or bosons, but I am particuarly interested in the bosonic case. I found this (https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.3156) result by Lu and Vishwanath that constructs the above scenario in the bosonic case but does it through a field theoretic perspective.

This may be an example of what you're looking for: https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.2121. Found it by doing a full-text search on arxiv with the keywords "U(1) SPT". I'll leave this as a comment, since I don't have much of an insight into the methods used in the paper.

Thank you! This is quite useful. Also embarrasingly I didn't try searching directly on arxiv... For posterity I found another paper that's relevant: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.13057
